# Gradle not picking the libraries which are copied dynamically under lib folder

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a requirement to load the different runtime libraries for a apk execution and unit test cases execution.

I am familiar with compile and testCompile scopes but problem is I don't want to load specific compile scope libraries while running the unit tests.

So I came up with some build.gradle like the below. I could able to copy the required jars/aars under the libs folder but these are not considered for class path.

Any thing wrong with this script?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

task getDynamicJars(type: Copy) {
        delete fileTree("$projectDir/libs/")
        if(project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains("test")){
            println("Loading Unit test dependencies");
            from "$rootDir/runtimeLibs/test/"
            into "$projectDir/libs/"
            include '**/*.*'

        }else{
            println("Loading Execute dependencies from:"+"$projectDir/runtimeLibs/execution/"+" To:"+"$projectDir/libs/");
            from "$rootDir/runtimeLibs/execution/"
            into "$projectDir/libs/"
            include '**/*.*'
        }

}

dependencies {
    println("Loading dependencies");
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    preBuild.dependsOn getDynamicJars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you like this solution:

```
def libsFolder
// ..
  buildTypes {
    release {
      // ..
      libsFolder = "${releaseLibsDir}"
    }

    debug {
      // ..
      libsFolder = "${debugLibsDir}"
    }
  }
// ..
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: "${libsFolder}", include: ['*.jar'])
}
```